# QtWebEngine: "Not allowed to load local resource" for iframe, how to disable web security?

Tags: javascript, html, qtwebengine

I'm porting my application from WebKit to WebEngine (seems that one is much better for rendering angular-basad html). 
I faced with problem that i can't enable QtWebEngine to load local iframe, despite the fact that i've setup all possible settings that i found:

Code from mainwindow.cpp

```
view->page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls, true);
view->page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, true);
view->page()->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::LocalStorageEnabled, true);

view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::LocalContentCanAccessFileUrls, true);
view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls, true);
view->settings()->setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings::LocalStorageEnabled, true);
```

The easiest example is to take WebEngine-based FancyBrowser (\Examples\Qt-5.4\webenginewidgets\fancybrowser) and try to load in it local html file like this:

Index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hi there</title>
</head>
<body>
    This is a page
    a simple page
    <iframe id="some_idrame" width="0" height="0" style="border: none" src="some_iframe.html" name="target" sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

some_iframe.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>La-la-la</title>
</head>
<body>
    Lalala 
</body>
</html>
```

If you setup env var QTWEBENGINE_REMOTE_DEBUGGING to some port, then you can open 127.0.0.1:port and see in console this error:

```
"Not allowed to load local resource".
```

I really have no idea how to solve this problem now... there should be some way to pass to WebEngine something like "--disable-web-security"...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: How are you opening it in fancy browser ? did you enter a file://<absolute_path>/index.html url ?

Comment: Also, please paste the complete error.
"Not allowed to load local resource: XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
What's the name of the file it complains about ?

Answer (score 1):

this Qt forum  link help you .
you should pass argument to application "--disable-web-security" 
https://forum.qt.io/topic/60691/not-allowed-to-load-local-resource-for-iframe-how-to-disable-web-security/4

Answer (score 1):

If you need to load local resource(s) by WebEngine, then you need to pass `--disable-web-security` argument to QApplication, e.g.:

```
char ARG_DISABLE_WEB_SECURITY[] = "--disable-web-security";
int newArgc = argc+1+1;
char** newArgv = new char*[newArgc];
for(int i=0; i<argc; i++) {
    newArgv[i] = argv[i];
}
newArgv[argc] = ARG_DISABLE_WEB_SECURITY;
newArgv[argc+1] = nullptr;

QApplication myApplication(newArgc, newArgv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to load the original page from the filesystem as well.  I was having issues loading images from Qt's resource system, so I subclassed QWebEngineView and created this function:

```
void WebEngineView::setLocalHtml(const QString &html)
{
    if(html.isEmpty())
    {
        setHtml(QString());
        return;
    }

    // Save html to a local file
    QString filePath;
    {
        QTemporaryFile tempFile(QDir::toNativeSeparators(QDir::tempPath() + "/ehr_temp.XXXXXX.html"));
        tempFile.setAutoRemove(false);
        tempFile.open();
        QTextStream out(&tempFile);
        out << html;

        filePath = tempFile.fileName();
    }

    // delete the file after it has been loaded
    QMetaObject::Connection * const conn = new QMetaObject::Connection;
    *conn = connect(this, &WebEngineView::loadFinished, [filePath, conn](){
        disconnect(*conn);
        delete conn;

        QFile::remove(filePath);
    });

    load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(filePath));
}
```

Since the main page is a local file as well, this gets around the CORS security problem.